# Does Openfire store custom message types (with PacketExtensions) offline?

Tags: java, xmpp, openfire

I have a custom message type with some of my own packet extensions. I need these messages to be stored when the recipient is offline. So far the server isn't storing them (yes, it is configured correctly). Does anyone know if Openfire will actually store offline custom message types? If not, is there anyway to force / trick / hack it so that it will?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer, yes it does, but you need to make sure the enclosing message's body is not null - just add some text.

Comment: great answer. Saved me a lot of hassle. Too bad I can only upvote once. Out of curiosity, how did you figure it out?